# Where does this trignometric substition come from?

Tags: calculus

When solving calculus problems sometimes they suggest setting 
$$x=\sqrt\frac ab sinu$$ can someone please explain where this subsitution comes from and explain the understanding of it?

Comment: can you give an example of where the substitution is used ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with $\sqrt {a - b x^2}$ lurking in it.  You want to find a substitution that makes that square root go away.

$\cos^2 t = 1-\sin^2 t$ is the would be the handy identity to employ.  If only you could get rid of those nasty constants.

You want $bx^2 = a \sin^2 t$ or $x = \sqrt {\frac{a}{b}} \sin t$
and when you subtitue $\sqrt {a - b x^2}$ becomes $\sqrt {a - a \sin^2 t} = \sqrt a \cos t$

great...but what about problems with $\sqrt {a + b x^2}$?

Try: $x = \sqrt {\frac{a}{b}} \tan t$