# Where does this trignometric substitution come from?

Tags: integration

to take the integral from $$\int_0^a \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$ but where does this substiution come from. $$x=\sqrt{a}/\sqrt{b} sinu$$ can someone please explain where it is dervied from, from which identity, and hence why it is an effective way to solve the problem

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \sin u$ or $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b} \sin u}$ ?

Comment: Not sure why you would even have $\sqrt{b}$ involved in the sub.

Comment: You asked a similar question last week.  If this answer was unsatisfying can you please give some idea why.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051442/where-does-this-trignometric-substition-come-from/2051458#2051458

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle. Choose any of the acute angles and label it $u$. The hypotenuse is length $a$, and the leg of the triangle adjacent to $u$ has length $x$. Use pythagoras to find the length of the other side. In this triangle, what is $\sin u$?

Answer (score 0):

I provided an algebraic answer to this question last week.  Lets try a geometric interpretation.

Your fuction $y = \sqrt {a^2 - x^2}$ is the the equation of for a semi-circle above the $x$ axis.

squaring both sides this becomes $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$

Integrating from 0 to a.  The means we wan the area of the quater circle.

Using only geometry we could jump to the answer $\frac {\pi a^2} 4.$

[image]

The substituion x = a sin u. now means that we are going to measure this region as the angle $u$ approach $\frac {\pi}{2}$

Why did I shade that green triangle?

Suppose we were not integrating from $0$ to $a$ but instead to $a'$

then  the region under the curve would be the pie peice plus the green triangle.

The area of the pie piece is $a^2 \sin^{-1} \frac {a'}{a}$  the area of the green triangle is $\frac 12 \cos \left(\sin^{-1} \frac {a'}{a}\right)\sin \left(\sin^{-1} \frac {a'}{a}\right)$

Why am I going through all of this?  To explain the additional terms that are going to pop up in the integration.

$\int_0^a \sqrt {a^2-x^2} dx\\
x = a \sin u\\
dx = a \cos u\;du$

limits of integration:

$x = 0\\
0 = a \sin u\\
\sin u = 0\\
u = 0$

$x = a\\
a = a \sin u\\
\sin u = 1\\
u = \frac \pi 2$

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sqrt {a^2 - a^2 \sin^2 u} (a \cos u \; du)\\
\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sqrt {a^2 \cos^2 u} (a \cos u) \; du\\
\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} a^2 \cos^2 u \; du$

now we use the half angle identity:

$\cos 2u = 2 \cos^2 u - 1\\
\cos^2 u = \frac 12 (1 + \cos 2u)$

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} a^2\frac 12(1+\cos 2u)\; du\\
a^2\frac 12(u+\frac 12 \sin 2u)|_0^{\frac \pi 2}$

$\sin 2u = 2 \cos u \sin u$

$a^2\frac 12(u+\cos u \sin u)|_0^{\frac \pi 2}$

And hopefully you can see that this is the same expression we had based on the purely geometrical interpretation.